# Gostaria de saber como estilizar os títulos do site, para ficarem com um traço em cada lado

Tags: html, css

Olá, gostaria de saber como estilizar os títulos do site, para ficarem com um traço em cada lado, para da a sensação de que está dividindo as paginas, em html, css e/js. Obrigado

Segue Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode usar flexbox para isso, criando dois pseudos-elementos, `::before` e `::after`, para construir as linhas (veja comentários explicativos no código):

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
   background: #000;
   font-size: 20px;
   color: #fff;
}

.titulo{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center; /* centraliza o texto horizontalmente */
   align-items: center; /* centraliza as linhas verticalmente */
   margin: 30px 0; /* 30px -> margens superior e inferior */
}

.titulo::before,
.titulo::after{
   content: '';
   position: relative;
   height: 1px; /* espessura das linhas */
   background: #666; /* cor das linhas */
   min-width: 50px; /* largura mínima das linhas */
   flex-grow: 1; /* distribui a largura das linhas por igual */
}

.titulo span{
   color: #fff; /* cor do texto */
   padding: 0 15px; /* distancia do texto às linhas */
   font-weight: bold; /* negrito */
   font-size: 2em; /* tamanho do texto */
}
```

```html
<div class="titulo">
   <span>Jr Luz</span>
</div>
<p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

Comment: Nossa, não havia pensado nessa solução, estava tentando fazer algo bem complexo rsrs, obrigado